# Set Session in my Controller C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, controller, web-config

I need to set a session variable in the controller and found that there are two ways of setting the session,
first is `Session["SessionId"] = "Session Value";`
second is `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionId"] = "Session Value";`
When using the first way I have to inherit the `: System.Web.HttpApplication`.
so my controller looks like this ->

```
public class LoginControllerWithSession : System.Web.HttpApplication
{        
    public Boolean userLoginSetSession(string username)
    {
        Session["username"] = username;
    }
}
```

My web.config looks like this ->

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc">
        <providers>
            <remove name="Session" />
            <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"
            preCondition="" />       
        </providers>
    </sessionState>
</system.web>
```

So the issue I'm having is when the `Session["username"] = username;` is run it throws an exception: `Session state is not available in this context.` and if I use the other way with `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session`, it will throw a null pointer exception. I don't understand what I'm missing. Everything I find researching says to just use the first method: `Session["SessionId"] = "Session Value";` and that should work, but it doesn't work for me. I'm guessing that I'm missing some configuration or whatever. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is your controller inheriting from System.Web.HttpApplication instead of Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem. I will show two different files with the proper code to enable the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionId"] = "Session Value";` to work.
Here is my WebApiConfig file located in the App_Start folder:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{

    public static string UrlPrefix { get { return "api"; } }
    public static string UrlPrefixRelative { get { return "~/api"; } }

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: WebApiConfig.UrlPrefix + "/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

This is the Global.asax file:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // starter code here
    }

    protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
    {
        if (IsWebApiRequest())
        {
            HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
        }
    }

    private bool IsWebApiRequest()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.StartsWith(WebApiConfig.UrlPrefixRelative);
    }
}
```

The Application_PostAuthorizeRequest and IsWebApiRequest are essential to using `HttpContext.Current`. Without these methods in the global.asax your `HttpContext.Current.Session` will always break with a null pointer exception.
I hope this helps anyone with the same problem I was running into where Session always throws null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Your *Controller* should indeed inherit from a *Controller*.  What I did to be able to build a *Session* easily, without too much complexity.  I built the following:

```
public class Storage
{
     public void SessionAdd(string label, string content)
     {
         if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(label) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
              return;

         HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(label, content);
     }

     public void SessionPurge()
     {
         var context = HttpContext.Current;
         if(context.Session != null)
              context.Session.Clear();
     }
}
```

That is a simple example, but your *Class* will have *access* to *using System.Web*.  Which will be able to correctly correlate a *Session*.  That is an example-

**Important:** When you build a *Session* for *Model View Controller* you should be cautious.  It is based on the premise of being *Stateless*.  So adding a *Session* may be incredibly difficult to keep track of, so you could end up with *rogue Session Variables* which could cause a potential problem.  So ensure that your application accounts for that potential and you track them very, very carefully.

Hopefully this helps you out.

Comment: When the application hits the HttpContext.Current.Session it breaks and throws a null pointer exception. I found some code, that I guess is missing, in the global.asax; its the session_start(Object sender, EventArgs e) but I'm still not sure how to use it. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I'd have to see your code, but you should be able to call it: `(new Storage()).SessionAdd("Example", example);` from your Controller.

Comment: It is possible to call the SessionAdd method, however when the application hits the `HttpContext.Current.Session` it throws a null pointer.

Comment: For the add or purge?  If you receive a null on add, it isn't properly pulling from the `System.Web` which should contain `HttpContext` or your server isn't allowing the Session to be stored.  I'll need to see your code.

Comment: I found the solution. I was missing a method in the global.asax `Application_PostAuthorizeRequest`. Now when I call the `HttpContext.Current.Session` it doesn't throw a null pointer.